# Laravel Query Builder weird column names conversion

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

I am trying to figure out why is DB::raw() queries are getting sent as lowercases?

```
Query = DB::('table_name')->select(['is_read as isRead'])->get();
Result = [{ isRead: true }]
```

But when I do raw its converting it to lowercase

```
Query = DB::('table_name')->select(DB::raw('is_read as isRead'))->get();
Result = [{ isread: true }]
```

I have a reason to use DB raw so I really need to figure this thing out.

Comment: same problem here : I need to use `DB:raw("DATE_PART ('month', DLUO)")` and I get the error `Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column dluo does not exist`. If I rename the column to `dluo` in lowercase, or if I don't use "raw" the issue disappears.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that when using `DB:raw` (or `orderByRaw` or any row `raw` methods) column names get converted to lowercase.

To avoid that, you can try to protect the name with quotes:

```
Query = DB::('table_name')->select(['is_read as "isRead"'])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce the issue you mention... Which version of Laravel are you using?

For instance, if I run the following:

```
DB::table('users')->select(DB::raw('is_read as isRead'))->get();
```

I would get the error:

> Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'is_read' in 'field list' (SQL: select is_read as isRead from `users`)'

Which is normal because I have no `is_read` column in my `users` table. However, you can see in the error that the `isRead` is not converted to lowercase.

Maybe you can use [selectRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#raw-methods) instead:

```
DB::table('table_name')->selectRaw('is_read as isRead')->get();
```

The query would be:

```
select is_read as isRead from `table_name`
```

Otherwise, could you update your question to provide more information on how to reproduce so your issue with the capitalization.

Comment: the code was actually like this DB::table('notifications')->select(DB::raw('CASE WHEN notifications.created_at IS NOT NULL THEN true ELSE false END as  isRead'))->get()

Comment: @rckyclsI still get the following query: `select CASE WHEN notifications.created_at IS NOT NULL THEN true ELSE false END as isRead from notifications`. Where are you seeing your lowercase result?